# Integrate a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, integrate

I am new to R. any help is welcome.
Let's say I have a function *A* in *R* that returns a matrix *A(x)*.
How i can I compute [image] ? 
I am aware of the existence of *integrate*, but this function works only with scalar functions.
thank you in advance

Comment: Can you give an example of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do a loop for it with rectangles or something.

```
res=0
for (i in seq(0,1,1/10000)[-10001])
    res=res+A(i)
res=res/10000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a good hack. I think I'll be using that until I find a new solution.